# LINQ to Objects auto increment number

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq-to-objects

This feels like a completely basic question, but, for the life of me, I can't seem to work out an elegant solution.

Basically, I am doing a LINQ query creating a new object from the query.  In the new object, I want to generate a auto-incremented number to allow me to keep a selection order for later use (named `Iter` in my example).

Here is my current solution that does what I need:

```
    Dim query2 = From x As DictionaryEntry In MasterCalendarInstance _
                 Order By x.Key _
                 Select New With {.CalendarId = x.Key, .Iter = 0}

    For i = 0 To query2.Count - 1
        query2(i).Iter = i
    Next
```

Is there a way to do this within the context of the LINQ query (so that I don't have to loop the collection after the query)?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Pardon me for doing this in C# not sure exactly the syntax in VB.NET:

```
MasterCalendarInstance
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
    .Select((x, ixc) => new { CalendarId = x.Key, Iter = ixc });
```

Comment: I don't quite see how this solves my problem.  how does the ixc value get populated and auto-incremented?

Comment: automagically :) it is an overload for the .Select extension method which takes a Func<T, int, TResult> (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if this is possible in VB, but in C# one uses a closure:

```
int count = 0
var res = from x in MasterCalendarInstance
          order by x.Key
          select new {
            CalendarId = x.Key,
            Iter = count++
          };
```

Comment: This was my first inclination (Gerneraly, I am a c# dude).  However, I am not aware of any vb.net version of ++ .  I was tempted to stick in a delegate method to handle this, but that adds more complication than I prefer in such a simple task.

Comment: +1 This works if you want to keep the code in query syntax instead of Lambda syntax.

Comment: `An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator`

Comment: @klent it is certainly OK in LINQ to Objects, but other LINQ providers are more restrictive. From the error I'm guessing you are using LINQ to Entities: you would need to do this kind of thing after performing the DB and getting back to in momory.

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions could be summed up in VB.NET like this :

```
MasterCalendarInstance _
    .OrderBy(Function (x) x.Key) _
    .Select(Function (x, ixc) New With { .CalendarId = x.Key,
                                         .Iter = ixc })
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this post while trying to solve a similar problem with a List(of String).

I'm posting my workaround in hopes that it may be adopted to resolve your issue, but more for anyone else who runs into this issue with a List(Of T).

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)
list.Add("Test1")
list.Add("Test2")
list.Add("Test3")

Dim var = list.Select(Function(s) New With {.Name = s, .RecordID = list.IndexOf(s)})
```

Hope this helps!